# AngularJS variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built an Angular app using Yeoman and Angular-fullstack-generator.
I want to have CRUD functions for an object called Book and wrote a bookIndex state as follow :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('bookIndex', {
        url: '/book',
        referrer: 'main',
        templateUrl: 'app/book/book.html',
        controller: function($state) {
          constructor($http, $scope, socket) {
            this.$http = $http;
            this.awesomeThings = [];
            $http.get('/api/book').then(response => {
              this.awesomeThings = response.data;
              socket.syncUpdates('thing', this.awesomeThings);
            });
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              socket.unsyncUpdates('thing');
            });
          }
          addThing() {
            if (this.newThing) {
              this.$http.post('/api/book', { name: this.newThing });
              this.newThing = '';
            }
          }
          deleteThing(thing) {
            this.$http.delete('/api/book/' + thing._id);
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

Grunt stop on "constructor($http, $scope, socket)" (unexpected token). I know that it has to do with variables among different scripts but I don't know exactly how to deal with it :-(

Sorry for this newbie question !!

Comment: Yeah, well, that code is nonsensical invalid syntax. Not sure what you're aiming for here.

Comment: I would suggest, instead of dumping everything at once, try adding few parts, running it and then repeating. That way you could get a better understanding of error/code.

Comment: i don't know about fullstack builder but i think the this.awesomeThings will have a problem of closure. This will point to the promise object instead of your service, use the var me = this; trick :). Maybe it's  constructor:function(...).

Answer (score 0):

After `controller: function($state) {` you have to pass the body of function, but it is looks like you try to declare class or object properties. It is not the right syntax for JavaScript.

For example it has to be:

```
 controller: function($state) {

     $scope.constructor($http, $scope);

     $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        // to do something
     });

     // and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the best practice ng-strict for your controller directives.

```
ng-strict-di=true
```

Now what you want to do is to initialize your controller in your app.js like so when using controllers in different js files:

```
 angular.module('app.mainView', ['ngRoute'])
 // not sure what your socket is, use the correct impl for factory, or service. If its an Angular services it should be $<name>.
.service('webSerivice', ['$http', '$q', 'webService'])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'webService', '$linq', MainCtrl])
```

To fix your code please try the following changes to your controller and note that this may not work with ng-strict.

You need to initialize whatever socket is

```
angular.module('myApp')
// now you can initialize socket
.service('socket' [<dependencies>, socket])

controller: function($state, $http, $scope, socket) {
        this.awesomeThings = [];
        $http.get('/api/book').then(response => {
          this.awesomeThings = response.data;
          socket.syncUpdates('thing', this.awesomeThings);
        });
        // rest of your code.
```